# Area 51, Super User, and Stack Overflow, what is the key different?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, area-51, specific-question, superuser

I have read from the about page of each site.

- Area 51
  (Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone)
- Super User
  (Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users)
- Stack Overflow
  (Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers)

I need a concise explanation for each of them, please. And also some example of simple topic that can be post in each site. Thanks

Comment: Did you read their help centers and about pages at all? These are 3 *very different* sites.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Yes but it seems too long to understand for me. Can you give the short different between those three please?

Comment: And clearly you figured out what Area51 is *for*, seeing as you posted a proposal there. As it stands, this question smacks of a spammy attempt to draw attention to your proposal. But maybe that is just me being cynical.

Comment: I've *removed* the Area51 proposal link from your post, it clearly has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: Yes you are right, Martijn. Indeed I make a proposal. I found a "create new discussion" option under my proposal headline. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: What is the difference between http://www.google.com and http://www.microsoft.com? Really, I think they are the same site can you help?

Comment: @SantosaSandy: What has that got to do with Stack Overflow and Super User? There is a discussion and help area on Area51 as well, did you look there? You post here doesn't ask anything about creating a new discussion on a proposal.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. That's what I read from the about page of the two site. @MartijnPieters I am not sure about which discussion in help Area51 that you mention about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My proposal is about specific topic so I don't have any intention to advertise it to everyone.

Comment: And I just wandering if only advance question can be post, may be it would be harder for a new user to learn.

Comment: Dear All, This question is put on hold as off-topic by Mr.Wizard, Martijn Pieters, Wooble, Azik, James. Shall I vote to delete this post or what do you suggest? I realize the reason why ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow?rq=1 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)** is for when you want to start an completely new Q&A site, or want to help others starting a site

**[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)** is for programming problems

**[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)** is for conceptual programming questions

**[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)** is for code reviews

**[Super User](http://superuser.com)** is for not-programming related computer usage questions

Comment: Thanks. It gives me some straight forward point for my understanding

Answer (score 3):

**Area 51** - you propose new Stack Exchange sites here. Do you have some hobby you want to discuss with fellow hobbyists? Check if there is an SE site for it and if not, propose its establishing.

**Super User** - for computer enthusiasts and power users. You ask questions about computers, operating systems and servers here.

**Stack Overflow** - for professional and enthusiast programmers. You ask questions about programming here, no matter what language you use.

Comment: Thanks, It seems you give a concise explanation that easier to be understad by me. I also know from you that we can ask question no matter what language we use.

Comment: In this case I mean about programming language.

Answer (score 3):

**Area 51** is the staging site for recommending new Stack Exchange sites. On this site you can see information on all of the sites that have been proposed and their current state of creation (or rejection) along with examples of the kinds of questions that should be asked on the new Stack Exchange site so that an understanding of what is on topic and off topic can be established before the site reaches a commitment phase.

**Super User** is for questions regarding using computers, computer hardware, and home networking. Questions here are often about configuring and customising operating systems, problems and errors that occur when running applications and configuring home networks.

**Stack Overflow** is for professional and enthusiast programmers to get assistance with problems they're experiencing when writing code. Questions on this site often include examples of code that the asker is experiencing issues in along with answers containing potential solutions and advice.

Comment: I see, so there would be a review between reach the commitment phase before any page can be aproved

Comment: Now I know that something related to computer use (hardware, network, instalation, etc.) can be asked in Super User

Comment: And anything related to code and programming would be suitable for Stack Overflow.